# why isn't sass confused by drive names on windows

Tags: windows, sass

I wasn't sure I should ask this on here, but I couldn't think of a better community, so I'll ask it here.

I'm using SASS to write my CSS on Windows, and the files are in my `C:\xampp\htdocs` folder. I'm using the SASS command-line directive:

```
sass --watch /path/to/scss/file:/path/to/css/file
```

However, the drives on Windows have colons in the names, so the syntax works like this:

```
sass --watch C:\xampp\htdocs\mysass.scss:C:\xampp\htdocs\mycss.css
```

Why isn't SASS confused by the colons in the drive names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

In the Ruby Sass implentation, which you are probably using, the developers built it like this:

```
def split_colon_path(path)
  one, two = path.split(':', 2)
  if one && two && Sass::Util.windows? &&
      one =~ /\A[A-Za-z]\Z/ && two =~ %r{\A[/\\]}
    # If we're on Windows and we were passed a drive letter path,
    # don't split on that colon.
    one2, two = two.split(':', 2)
    one = one + ':' + one2
  end
  return one, two
end
```

[full source](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/stable/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb#L417)

As you can see, there is a check for the OS. If the current OS is Windows, they split the arguments on the second colon instead of the first one.

**Old:**

Depending on which wrapper you use for running Sass, there are libraries for resolving filepaths OS-agnostically.

If you run node-sass (Node.js wrapper) for example, sass will make use of the node.js [`path`-utility](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) to pipe the I/O to and from Sass.

**Example in node.js**

Windows:

```
> path.resolve()
'C:\\Users\\tom_m'
```

GNU\Linux (Ubuntu)

```
> path.resolve()
'/home/tom_m'
```

That means, how filepaths get resolved is not specific to sass but to the wrapper you are using.

To find out how your libSass-wrapper handles the paths look for it on http://sass-lang.com/libsass and search for the corresponding project on github.

You can find the node-sass wrapper here: https://github.com/sass/node-sass